# how to check and avoid funtions having same names in one static library?

Tags: c

I'm confusing when creating a static library in C/C++ with same funtion names and param lists but implemented in different source files.

Say, I have `play()` funtion declared in `test.h`, and `play()` implemented in both `test.c` and `test_old.c`. When creating a library that include both `test.c` and `test_old.c` in usually manner, there will be no error.

But this will make people confusing when using this library. How to detect this replicated implementation?Thanks.

Comment: Your question tags C, not C++. In C a (simple) lib is just a bunch of object files. A simple lib manager (probably) doesn't care about multiply defined symbols. Upon linking a problem may be reported, or a stupid linker just takes the first symbol (object with that symbol) it encounets and ignores the rest. Of course there can be smarter lib managers and linkers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yeah, you are right, I'm building a pure C library in this example, and it is simplified from my real project/source files, which including both C and C++ files. They two have same kind of behavior(same function in static lib with no error or warning).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What do you mean by mentioning "smarter lib managers and linkers"?  Do you mean clang v.s. gcc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicating function names in your static library is **very** bad practice. Don't do this.

That said you can check for duplicate definitions by examining the output of the `nm` application.

```sh
$ nm libstest.a

test1.c.o:
0000000000000000 T bla

test2.c.o:
0000000000000000 T bla
```

The following command lists duplicate functions in your library:

```sh
$ nm libstest.a | grep -P "^[^\\s]+ T " | cut -d' ' -f3 | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, this works. But I'm also curious if I can check that when building that static library, i.e. some flags passing to GCC compiler.

Comment: Not as far as I know. This problem is far more uncommon than you may think. In bigger projects there wouldn't be a function called `play()`. For example if `play()` was used to start playback of a soundfile it would be called something along the lines of `sound_start_playback()` or `audiofile_play()`. Project structure should ensure that it's immediately obvious in which file that function is located and gcc will make sure that no function is duplicated in a single file.